# Copper, Silver and Gold. Who had what?

Tags: logical-deduction, situation

I made the following riddle in a RPG.

> *Albus*, *Baku* and *Croco* experimented with some ingots. One was using copper, one silver and the other gold.
>
> But none of the experiments worked with the ingots they had. Though another could.
>
> After some changes, *Baku* ended up richer than before. *(gold is more expensive than silver, which is more expensive than copper, just in case)*
>
> *Croco* tried to help *Baku* with his experiment.
>
> There was no mutual exchange of ingots.
>
> *Albus* is deadly allergic to silver.

Players could take what *Albus* had after everything happened, if they guessed what it could be, according to the riddle.

How rich they became?

EDIT to clarify:

The nature of the experiments is not important at all (you can think of *Albus*, *Baku* and *Croco* as alchemists). The important thing here is who had which ingots at the begining and who had them at the end.

Hint:

> It's about logic, as the already given answers point. Even though, you shouldn't make more assumptions than those said.

EDIT to make clear the assumptions of the riddle:

> *Albus* had an ingot. *Baku* had an ingot. *Croco* had an ingot. One of the ingots was gold, another silver, another copper.
>
> Some ingots changed their owner, with no mutual exchange. *(if A gave his ingot to B, B did not gave his ingot to A)*
>
> *Baku* recieved an ingot that make him richer
>
> *Croco* gave his ingot to *Baku*
>
> *Albus* never touched silver.

You have to guess what can *Albus* have after everything that's consistent with previous statements and is the maximum possible

Comment: What is the purpose of the experiments?  Do they use copper / silver / gold *to* experiment the ingots, or those are the ingots?  I can't quite get what you mean for the entire question...

Comment: @Alex I hope it's clarified enough now.

Comment: considering all the comments you have posted on our answers, I am presuming that this is not a logic puzzle as much has a "find the loophole" puzzle.

Comment: It's a logic puzzle. Though everybody is making an assumption about something that's not said.

Comment: Again, thinking outside of the box might help.

Comment: What is the assumption everyone is making? My answer proves that, in your writing, you are making assumptions. Perhaps you should clarify this for the rest of the class.

Comment: It's the most important assumption that almost solves the problem... You assume that you only give if you recieve something

Comment: I thought that might be it. As such, I reworked my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starts off:

> Albus - Gold
>
> Baku - Copper
>
> Croco - Silver

Then they shift:

> Albus - Copper
>
> Baku - Silver
>
> Croco - Gold

Then

> Croco gives Albus gold and Albus gives nothing back (not a mutual exchange since Croco gets nothing in return)

So Albus ends up with

> The Copper and Gold ingots

As for thinking out of the box:

> Baku gives Albus his silver bar as well (for nothing in return), except he puts it directly into Albus' bank (with no contact betwee the silver and Albus) in which Albus can now exchange it for its cash/copper/gold value.
>
>  If Baku is evil, he kills Albus for us, so that we inherit his ingots!
>
>  Which means Albus [me] gets all the ingots (gold, silver and copper)

Comment: That's a creative solution, though the idea is to find a solution, consistent with the premises, that gives *Albus* the most value, since that's what players could keep after the riddle.

Comment: I don't get the grand finale. But as said, you can end up with gold and copper

Comment: @AlbertMasclans This doesn't really rely on logic. Nowhere is it even implied that Croco would have given his ingot to Albus. Since everyone else keeps the ingot they ended with, why should we assume that Albus would get his initial ingot back?

Comment: As said, you shall find the outcome that ends up with Albus the richest

Answer (score 2):

Let's use the metals' atomic abbreviations to identify which one each person has. They are:

- Cu for Copper
- Ag for Silver
- Au for Gold

We start out knowing that Albus cannot have used silver. Then, seeing as Baku got richer, he could not have had gold. If we draw this out a bit, we get...

> Albus - NOT Ag
> Baku - Cu OR Ag
> Croco - Unknown

Working with these, we conclude that, at the start of the experiments, these people have these metals:

> Albus - Au
> Baku - Ag
> Croco - Cu

After the experiments initially fail, some changes are made. At this point, we can utilize the knowledge that Baku becomes richer. Now, knowing humans and their tendency to feel greed and envy, Croco may have gotten jealous of Baku's increased wealth. Now, we can draw this conclusion:

> Albus - Cu
> Baku - Au
> Croco - Ag

Using this drawing, the final answer is that

> Albus has the copper.

However, there is also another path. It contravenes what one might expect to happen, but it is a better path for the player who is trying to solve the riddle. This path goes as follows.

> Albus starts with copper, Baku with silver, and Croco with gold. After the swap, Baku has gold, and Croco has copper. This leaves us with Albus.

If we were to take this path, we would end with this:

> Albus has the silver. However, unfortunately for Albus, his silver allergy has resulted in his death.

Comment: Your logic is correct. Even though, since players get to keep what *Albus* had, the best answer to the riddle is the one that ends with *Albus* having the most. There's a better answer. Think outside the box.

Comment: I really love your alternative. There's, though, one that's even more lucrative.

Comment: Oh, wow. I'll definitely have fun with this one. :P

Answer (score 2):

With the clarified logic:

Start:

> Albus - Copper
>
> Baku - Silver
>
> Croco - Gold

End:

> Albus - Gold
>
> Baku - Silver & Copper
>
> Croco - None

Albus had an ingot. Baku had an ingot. Croco had an ingot. One of the ingots was gold, another silver, another copper.

> Albus - Copper
>
> Baku - Silver
>
> Croco - Gold

But none of the experiments worked with the ingots they had. Though another could.

> They had to move all the ingots around
> Albus - Gold
>
> Baku - Copper
>
> Croco - Silver

Some ingots changed their owner, with no mutual exchange. (if A gave his ingot to B, B did not gave his ingot to A)

> **Some** implies that not all ingots had to change hands. We'll get to what this means in a moment

Baku recieved an ingot that make him richer
Croco gave his ingot to Baku

> Croco, after failing in his experiment, gave his silver ingot to Baku. Now, Baku has both the silver and the copper ingots, making him richer than before.

Albus never touched silver.

> Albus started with copper and ended with gold

<s>Why not:</s>

> Albus starts with the gold and the copper ingots and ends with the gold

Here's the deal:

Albus, Baku and Croco experimented with some ingots. One was using copper, one silver and the other gold.

> This never states that they all come to the table holding one ingot. At this point, Albus could have all three.

But none of the experiments worked with the ingots they had. Though another could.

> OK, we have to take one away from Albus. Because we later learn about his allergy, we say he never had the silver, that Croco had it the whole time.

After some changes, Baku ended up richer than before. (gold is more expensive than silver, which is more expensive than copper, just in case)

> Baku came in without anything. By getting the silver ingot, he walks away richer than before.

Croco tried to help Baku with his experiment.

> Croco gave Baku the ingot to work on, since he didn't have one.

There was no mutual exchange of ingots.

> Albus gave Croco the copper ingot because he gave the silver up to Baku to be able to work

Albus is deadly allergic to silver.

> So Albus never handled the silver ingot

Comment: In my oppinion "One was using copper, one silver and the other gold." implies that each one had one ingot. Even though, not assuming things is what leads to a great answer! Mine is not this one, but yours is great.

Answer (score 1):

Albus had platinum at the end.

> 1.  Albus is allergic to silver means that he neither started with nor ended with silver.
>
> 2.  Croco helped Baku.  This means that Baku could not have helped Croco (otherwise Albus ends up with the same thing.  Thus Baku must have helped Albus and Albus helped Croco.  This implies that Croco must have given silver to Baku (otherwise Albus had the silver at some point.
>
> 3.  Baku ended up richer.  As Baku was given silver (from 2), this means he started with copper.  Thus he gave the copper to Albus (who therefore must have started with gold and given it to Croco.
>
> Beginning: Albus: gold, Baku: copper, Croco: silver
> End: Albus: copper, Baku: silver, Croco: gold
>
>   EDIT* For Albus to have the MOST at the end, it means that his experiment must have worked.  If they are alchemists, then we'll assume he turned his copper into PLATINUM.  The statement "Croco TRIED to help Baku" suggests that he didn't actually help his experiment.  This means that Baku actually needed the gold for his experiment.  Croco's experiment may or may not have worked.  Nothing says that each one's experiment needs a different metal.

Comment: Your logic is correct. Even though, since players get to keep what *Albus* had, the best answer to the riddle is the one that ends with *Albus* having the most. There's a better answer. Think outside the box.

Comment: Then Albus' experiment worked and he ended up with Platinum.

Answer (score 1):

> Albus has the copper ingot, Baku has the silver, and Croco has the gold.
>  Originally Albus had gold, Baku had copper, and Croco had silver.

... logic chain ...

> Everyone switched ingots (no mutual exchange, so all must have moved).
>  Baku upgraded, so he must have ended with silver or gold.
>  Croco tried to help Baku, so he must have started out with an ingot worth more.
>  Since Albus can't touch it, the silver was exchanged between Croco and Baku.
>  If Albus had the copper, he must have passed it to Croco since Baku does not have the copper -- but this is impossible because Baku could not have given Albus the silver to take Croco's gold.
>  Therefore Albus started with the gold.
>  Since Baku upgraded, he must have started with the copper to Croco's silver or the help wouldn't have been needed.
>  The ingots were passed Albus gold to Croco, Croco silver to Baku, and Baku copper to Albus.

Comment: Your logic is correct. Even though, since players get to keep what *Albus* had, the best answer to the riddle is the one that ends with *Albus* having the most. There's a better answer. Think outside the box.

Answer (score 1):

> Albus had gold -> switched to copper

-

> Baku had silver -> switched to gold

-

> Carno had copper -> switched to silver

are the only combinations that fit all the criteria (I interpreted Carno help Baku as Carno picking the metal Baku had left off)

Comment: Your logic is correct. Even though, since players get to keep what *Albus* had, the best answer to the riddle is the one that ends with *Albus* having the most. There's a better answer. Think outside the box.

Comment: then the only trick I see is that which metal Albus "had" is not clear wether  it refers to what he had before the switch or after the switch. Albus "had" gold at some point (to begin with) he just didn't end up with it.

Comment: Clarified. Though you should think this *Albus* not ending up with gold again.